# Packet loss resulting in bad framerate during webrtc call

Tags: c#, .net, video, uwp, webrtc

I am working on a webrtc implementation for uwp using the following sdk: https://github.com/webrtc-uwp/webrtc-uwp-sdk/tree/releases/m71

The implementation generally works fine though I am having some issues with call quality when packet loss occurs. What happens is that when a packet or a few packets are lost framerate decreases a lot. Think from 30 FPS to less than 1 FPS. The audio is fine however. This would not be a problem if my client would recover when connection is improved again. However at this moment, if the problem occurs then the video is bad for the rest of the call.

I do not know where the issue might lay. As I understand it webrtc is supposed to compensate for packet loss? I was thinking that the issue might be in the sdk I am using. When I get a videotrack from the other peer I just connect it to a mediaelement in uwp so I do not handle the incoming frames myself. As a side note I have tested to just pause the debugger during a call and this also results in bad framerate both for the remote and local track. However worth to note is that even when my local video gets bad framerate it looks good on the other client. This would indicate that something is not working when playing video from a video track locally.

I include my local sdp just in case it is something wrong with that one:

```
v=0
o=- 3875426963439162405 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=video 52241 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 98
c=IN IP4 ...MY IP ADRESS...
b=AS:1264
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
... SOME ICE CANDIDATES ...
a=ice-ufrag:6ZNW
a=ice-pwd:1JMvi96Ju3YZCX9S+ChJNH2C
a=fingerprint:sha-256 7B:F5:B5:49:E7:76:54:5F:55:D6:D3:2E:97:38:E0:63:63:5F:2E:53:49:BC:BD:B9:1D:40:45:4B:EC:1E:EE:D4
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=extmap:10 http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-avtext-framemarking-07
a=extmap:9 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=sendrecv
a=msid:- SELF_VIDEO
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=fmtp:98 x-google-profile-id=0
a=ssrc-group:FID 2190372283 111930078
a=ssrc:2190372283 cname:C+phDL3HvwhlyByD
a=ssrc:2190372283 msid: SELF_VIDEO
a=ssrc:2190372283 mslabel:
a=ssrc:2190372283 label:SELF_VIDEO
a=ssrc:111930078 cname:C+phDL3HvwhlyByD
a=ssrc:111930078 msid: SELF_VIDEO
a=ssrc:111930078 mslabel:
a=ssrc:111930078 label:SELF_VIDEO
m=audio 52242 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 ...MY IP ADRESS...
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
... SOME ICE CANDIDATES ...
a=ice-ufrag:6ZNW
a=ice-pwd:1JMvi96Ju3YZCX9S+ChJNH2C
a=fingerprint:sha-256 7B:F5:B5:49:E7:76:54:5F:55:D6:D3:2E:97:38:E0:63:63:5F:2E:53:49:BC:BD:B9:1D:40:45:4B:EC:1E:EE:D4
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:1
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:9 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=sendrecv
a=msid:- SELF_AUDIO
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=ssrc:2339515350 cname:C+phDL3HvwhlyByD
a=ssrc:2339515350 msid: SELF_AUDIO
a=ssrc:2339515350 mslabel:
a=ssrc:2339515350 label:SELF_AUDIO
```

Any help or suggestions as to what might be wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the framerate decreases to 1fps? That is too low. I would advice you  to check the exact framerate with different conditions, this can give you some more detailed information about the issue. You can do it for free in Loadero, here are some resources, that will help you create some free tests to get insights:

- A blog post with a guide to testing webRTC apps  https://blog.loadero.com/2020/08/10/how-to-set-up-an-automated-webrtc-test-with-loadero/
- Info about setting network conditions, packet loss, jitter and more  https://wiki.loadero.com/test-creation/participant-configuration/network-conditions
- How to use post-run assertions, this will allow you get exact FPS https://blog.loadero.com/2020/01/29/how-to-get-the-best-out-of-post-run-assertions/
- Sign up here to run those tests and get detailed data  https://loadero.com/home

Running tests with different network conditions will help you get detailed info about which network issues cause the FPS decrease and how much of a decrease that is. Hope this will allow you to find the issue in your application.

Comment: Hi Pāvels! Thanks for the suggestion. I looked into the Loadero and it does not seem to be applicable for what I am testing here. I am fairly certain that framerate is the issue here. It seems at this point that the frames aren't being decoded fast enough so a new keyframe is requested too often. I will look into this.